# why $xy^{(4)} + 2y'' + (xy')^5 = x^3$ is of the fourth order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I came across this equation from the book [*Ordinary Differential Equations*](https://books.google.com.gh/books/about/Ordinary_Differential_Equations.html?id=iU4zDAAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y) (Lesson 3A page 31) 
$$xy^{(4)} + 2y'' + (xy')^5 = x^3$$

I don't know why it was regarded as **a fourth order differential equation**. Or does it mean that $$xy^{(4)} = xy''''$$ 
I am a bit confused

Comment: Your interpretation is correct. $y'=y^{(1)}$ and $y''=y^{(2)}$

Comment: Yes, $f^{(n)}$ is the $n$-th derivative of $f$.

Comment: thanks for the explanation

Comment: It's inhomogeneous non linear and of fourth order because the higjest derivative is a fourth derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that $y^{(4)}=y''''$. For higher derivatives the latter notation becomes messy and hard to read, which is why it is common to see $y^{(n)}$ if $n$ becomes large, but also $y'$ and $y''$ in the same equation.

See also: [Lagrange's notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Lagrange's_notation).